# identifying and extracting elements (button ,text field ...) from a screenshot of GUI using python

Tags: python, opencv, user-interface

I am searching for a way to identify and extract elements (button ,text field ...) from a GUI screenshot using python and opencv.

when I read opencv-python documentation, I found only a method that identify shapes based on their color but what I need is a method that can identify shapes based on their form.

example :

s30.postimg.org/mvobf4b4x/Simple4.jpg

Comment: This is really a big topic. You ask for an image processing algorithm....

Comment: yes I am asking if there is an image processing algorithm or a library that can fit my need